# Make one big column out of several in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns, tidyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe in a bit of an unfortunate format. I have several values which should be part of one column in a table format, like below:

```
X_1     X_2     X_3             X_4             X_5     
Wasser  Strand  Zangen          Beine           Schmerz 
Wasser  Meer    rot             Steine          beißen  
Rot     Lecker  Restaurant      Teuer           Gourmet 
Zellen  Leid    Schmerzen       Chemotherapie   Tot 
rot     Krallen tödlich         Schmerzen       schlimm 
Hummer  salz    sternzeichen    krankheit       rot 
Wasser  Meer    Sternzeichen    Krankheit       Tumor
```

I would like to make my dataframe look "tidy", therefore, I would like to stack the several columns into one column, like this:

```
X_1
Wasser
Wasser
Rot
Zellen
rot
Hummer
Wasser
Strand
Meer
Lecker
Leid
Krallen
....
```

And this needs to be done for several "blocks".  Is there a way to do this within the `tidyverse` framework? I tried messing around with `gather()` but I couldn't make it work...

To provide a small code snippet, a reproducible example could be made from this:

```
matrix(1:40, ncol = 8)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21   26   31   36
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22   27   32   37
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23   28   33   38
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24   29   34   39
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40
```

And the result I would like to have would look like this:

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1   21
 [2,]    2   22
 [3,]    3   23
 [4,]    4   24
 [5,]    5   25
 [6,]    6   26
 [7,]    7   27
 [8,]    8   28
 [9,]    9   29
[10,]   10   30
[11,]   11   31
[12,]   12   32
[13,]   13   33
[14,]   14   34
[15,]   15   35
[16,]   16   36
[17,]   17   37
[18,]   18   38
[19,]   19   39
[20,]   20   40
```

Comment: Why has the expected output two columns? Do you always want to reshape multi-column data into two columns? What is the rule? The expected output from your first example seems to have a single column.

Comment: Hi Maurits. This rule has to be repeated for several "blocks", about 60 times actually, but I figured, once I get the hang of reshaping the dataframe, I could apply it over all "blocks" where needed! This is why the examples don't match... Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Hi Inkling. That didn't answer my question. But that aside, this sounds like a simple recast, as @Wimpel demonstrates. If this is not what you want, please give a more representative example and clearly state the rule for the number of columns in your final output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT] I haven't seen the answer from @Wimpel. So with `data.frame` and more complicated pattern I see following solution:

```
> df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:40, ncol = 8))
> df
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
1  1  6 11 16 21 26 31 36
2  2  7 12 17 22 27 32 37
3  3  8 13 18 23 28 33 38
4  4  9 14 19 24 29 34 39
5  5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40
> pattern = list(c(1,3), c(2, 5), c(4, 7), c(6, 8))
> data.frame(sapply(pattern, function(x) unlist(df[x])))
    X1 X2 X3 X4
V11  1  6 16 26
V12  2  7 17 27
V13  3  8 18 28
V14  4  9 19 29
V15  5 10 20 30
V31 11 21 31 36
V32 12 22 32 37
V33 13 23 33 38
V34 14 24 34 39
V35 15 25 35 40
```

Comment: How is this different from @Wimpel's earlier answer?

Comment: I haven't seen it when I wrote the answer. I've added the edit

Comment: Wimpel's answer was up for nearly 10 minutes before you posted yours. In order to reduce clutter and redundancy it is expected that you check your answer against already posted answers *prior* to posting.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you @utubun

Comment: Yeap, but I have experienced this problem several times already. I am not very quick in writing, so maybe that is the reason. Of course the first part is a duplicate of Wimpel's answer. I will do another edit to delete it.

Comment: @lnkling I'am glad it helped!

Comment: the same approach can be used with  a matrix: `mtx <- matrix(1:40, ncol = 8); colgroups <- list(1:4, 5:8); sapply(colgroups, function(i) unlist(mtx[,i]))`

Comment: @utubun No worries; nice solution. +1

Comment: @Maurits Evers Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No need for tidyverse.

Create a new matrix from your previous one.. set number of columns, and fill by column (byrow = FALSE)

```
m <- matrix(1:40, ncol = 8)
matrix(m, ncol = 2, byrow = FALSE)

      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1   21
 [2,]    2   22
 [3,]    3   23
 [4,]    4   24
 [5,]    5   25
 [6,]    6   26
 [7,]    7   27
 [8,]    8   28
 [9,]    9   29
[10,]   10   30
[11,]   11   31
[12,]   12   32
[13,]   13   33
[14,]   14   34
[15,]   15   35
[16,]   16   36
[17,]   17   37
[18,]   18   38
[19,]   19   39
[20,]   20   40
```

Comment: You can even omit `byrow = FALSE` as this is the default.

Comment: `matrix(as.matrix(df), ncol = 2)` or `matrix(sapply(df, as.character), ncol = 2)`

Comment: Thank you! What I needed :)

Comment: Just to celebrate the differences :)  there is also another way producing the same results:

`dim(m) <- c(20, 2)`